# A question about the limit of a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Consider the following function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ defined, for fixed but arbitrary $t \in \mathbb R$, as:
$$f(x)= \left(e^{itx} - 1 - \frac{itx}{1+x^2}  \right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}$$

I am trying to show that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)= \frac{-1}{2}t^2$$

Help!

Comment: André, what have you tried in order to solve your exercise? Write it in your question and I will help you.

Comment: $$f(x)= \left(e^{itx} - 1 - \frac{itx}{1+x^2}  \right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}=\left(e^{itx} - 1\right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2} - \frac{it}{x}   $$

for real numbers, I know that $e^x-1 \approx x$, for $x \approx 0$. So, (assuming the same for complex) 
$$f(x)\approx itx\frac{1+x^2}{x^2} - \frac{it}{x}=it\frac{1+x^2}{x} - \frac{it}{x}=itx $$

Comment: André, you should write what you tried not as a comment but in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the expansion
\begin{align*}
e^{itx}=1+itx-\frac{t^2x^2}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{(itx)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
and simplify. Since the sequence of functions $(f_N)_{N\geq 3}$ with
\begin{align*}
f_N(x)=\sum_{n=3}^N\frac{(itx)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
converges uniformly on each compact subset within a disc of radius $R>0$ and center $0$ we can exchange limits and obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{N\to\infty} f_N(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(0)=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try and be right back.

Comment: I have 
$$f(x) = itx - \frac{t^2}{2}(1+x^2) + (1+x^2)\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{(it)^n x^{n-2}}{n!}$$
If $x\to 0$, we have $x^{n-2}\to 0$ for each $n\geq 3$, but I dont have an argument to say that the infnite sum of small numbers (approaching to zero) is finite (for example $\sum_{n} 1/n = \infty$). Can you cite the argument to show that $\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{(it)^n x^{n-2}}{n!}< \infty$.

Comment: @AndréGoulart: I've added a reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'hopital's Rule, but change the product into an equivalent quotient first.

$$f(x)= \left(e^{itx} - 1 - \frac{itx}{1+x^2}  \right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{itx} - 1 - \frac{itx}{1+x^2} }{x^2/(1+x^2)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ite^{itx}+\frac{(-it)(1+x^2)+2x(itx)}{(1+x^2)^2}}{\frac{2x(1+x^2)-2x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ite^{itx}(1+x^2)^2-it+itx^2}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-t^2e^{itx}(1+x^2)^2+4itxe^{itx}(1+x^2)+2itx}{2}=\frac{-t^2}{2}$$